# NavigationManager's startNavigation() has blank map

Tags: skmaps

I'm trying to use turn by turn navigation using SKNavigationManager's startNavigation(navigationSettings). Interestingly it works flawless in 'Simulation' mode but when I switch to 'Real' mode there is no map on the screen. It's just that the map is not drawn on screen, but the rest like annotations and other stuff are populated and working fine.

I've used SKToolsNavigatoinManager and it works fine, but I don't want to use it as it has a lot of UI interfaces which are not useful for my application.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the settings and the navigationManager code I'm using

```
SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings = new SKNavigationSettings();
SKNavigationManager navigationManager = SKNavigationManager.getInstance();
navigationSettings.setNavigationType(SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationType.REAL);
navigationSettings.setNavigationMode(SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationMode.PEDESTRIAN);
navigationManager.setMapView(navMapView);
navigationManager.startNavigation(navigationSettings);
```

If i don't use the navigationManager.setMapView(navMapView); I get a different view.

[1. This is how the screen looks like after I start navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHlDl.jpg) 

[2. This is how the screen looks like before navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFACG.jpg)

Comment: Is the map drawn on the screen before the navigation is started?

Comment: Yes, the map is drawn before navigation started, I've attached the image to the question now. I've also attached the Image of screen after starting navigation.

Comment: I tried adding images, but my rep wouldn't allow me to do so, I somehow managed to get the screenshots hyperlinked in the question. Please have a look at them if you need more details.

Comment: [3. Screen when mapView is not set](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9fcOMzLobZadnVwOTBtUVg5ejA) If i don't add the mapView attribute to the navigationManager i have something similar to a NavigationScreen but it's static and won't update anything.

Comment: Are you using the latest SDK version which is 3.0.3?

Comment: I downloaded the SDK from skobbler and then added the jar to project, not sure what version it is. I think I'm using 3.0.2 (found it in app.gradle) if this is not the version where do I find it?

Comment: That is the SDK version that I use and I have never experienced a similar problem. Have u tried changing .Pedestrian to .Car to see if that would work?

Comment: Just found that the map is actually being drawn, but the current location is set to [0,0], I've verified the currentLocationProvier updates are giving out correct location but something is missing where the navigationManager is not receiving the correct location updates. [View when  zoomed out](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9fcOMzLobZaeHdZVUNXbVBRMGc)

Comment: Do you have `navMapView.getMapSettings().setFollowPositions(true);`

Comment: Yes, I've set it and tried but still the current position is in the ocean near africa.

Comment: Inside your SKCurrentPositionListener do you have `SKPositionerManager.getInstance().reportNewGPSPosition(currentPosition);`?

Comment: No, I was missing just this one step. Once I've setup the SKPositionerManager the map started to populate in correct position. Thankyou @SmedleyDSlap

Comment: No problem glad I was able to help. Accept my answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is drawn to the screen its just centered at the point [0,0] which is in the middle of the Atlantic ocean therefore the screen is blue. To have the camera follow the current location you must do the following 2 steps:

1. Set follow positions to true on your SKMapView object: `navMapView.getMapSettings().setFollowPositions(true);`
2. Create a SKCurrentPositionProvider and set the SKCurrentPositionListener

   ```
   SKCurrentPositionProvider positionProvider = new SKCurrentPositionProvider(activity);
   positionProvider.setCurrentPositionListener(new SKCurrentPositionListener(){

       @Override
       public void onCurrentPositionUpdate(SKPosition currentPosition) {
           SKPositionerManager.getInstance().reportNewGPSPosition(currentPosition);

       }

   });
   positionProvider.requestLocationUpdates(true, true, false);
   ```